# Update data in DataGrid using entity framework database first and MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm, datagrid

In my Current WPF application, I am using the well known MVVM pattern.

I have a DataGrid as follows:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource GroupsViewSource}}" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedGroup}" 
          AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False"
          SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit="FullRow" 
          EnableRowVirtualization="False" VirtualizingPanel.IsContainerVirtualizable="False" >

    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="RowEditEnding">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataGridRowEditEndingCommand}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>

    <DataGrid.Columns>

        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Group Name" Width="*" SortMemberPath="GroupName">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding GroupName}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding GroupName}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Parent Group" Width="*" SortMemberPath="ParentID">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ParentID, Converter={StaticResource parentIDToGroupNameConverter}}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ParentGroupsViewSource}}" 
                              DisplayMemberPath="GroupName"
                              SelectedValue="{Binding ParentID, Converter={StaticResource parentIDToGroupNameConverter}}" SelectedValuePath="GroupName"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Edit" Width="50" IsReadOnly="True">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Button x:Name="btnEdit" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=EditButton}" Height="35" Width="35" 
                                Visibility="{Binding DataContext.IsInEdit, 
                                                     RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, 
                                                     Converter={StaticResource boolToVisibilityInverseConverter}}" 
                                Click="EditSaveButton_Click" 
                                Command="{Binding DataContext.EditCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"/>
                        <Button x:Name="btnSave" Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=SaveButton}" Height="35" Width="35" 
                                Visibility="{Binding DataContext.IsInEdit, 
                                                     RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, 
                                                     Converter={StaticResource boolToVisibilityConverter}}" 
                                Click="EditSaveButton_Click"
                                Command="{Binding DataContext.SaveCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Delete" Width="70" IsReadOnly="True">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Button x:Name="btnDelete" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=DeleteButton}" Height="35" Width="35"
                                Visibility="{Binding DataContext.IsInEdit, 
                                                     RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, 
                                                     Converter={StaticResource boolToVisibilityInverseConverter}}" 
                                Command="{Binding DataContext.DeleteCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"/>
                        <Button x:Name="btnCancel" Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=CancelButton}" Height="35" Width="35" 
                                Visibility="{Binding DataContext.IsInEdit, 
                                                     RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, 
                                                     Converter={StaticResource boolToVisibilityConverter}}" 
                                Command="{Binding DataContext.CancelCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

    </DataGrid.Columns>

</DataGrid>
```

As you can see in the above mentioned XAML, I am using a command for RowEditEnding instead of an event. Now when user has completed editing a row, I want to save that changes to the database. If I was using code-behind pattern, then I would have easily said `e.Row.Item` and I might have got the data. But in MVVM I have tried as follows:

```
//I Have a DelegateCommand called DataGridRowEditEndingCommand. 
//Method corresponding to this command is as follows:

private void DataGridRowEditEnding()
{
    SaveToDataBase();
}

private void SaveToDataBase()
{
    Group currentGroup = db.Groups.Where(x => x.GroupID == SelectedGroup.GroupID).FirstOrDefault();
    if (currentGroup != null)
    {
        db.Entry(currentGroup).CurrentValues.SetValues(SelectedGroup);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

When I keep a breakpoint in SaveToDataBase method, I can see that values in SelectedGroup are not changed.

I am totally out of memory here.......

Am I doing the right thing in above code??????

Comment: You didn't bind `EF entities` directly to the grid right? What's the `GroupsViewSource`, it seems to be your `ViewModel`, does it contain your `EF entities`?

Comment: No, GroupsViewSource is not a ViewModel. It is a CollectionViewSource. and this CollectionViewSource is bound to a property called Groups in my ViewModel.